# admob , adsense , iAds or any other advertisement could be handle from app Admin panel?

Tags: admob, iad

I would Like to know that is there any way through which I could achieve the below task:

iads - on/off does not let me rotate. For instance we want to have full control when we add an 'add' if we have sold an adv placement (banner w/link) it should show up ... but then in places where we have not sold adv. it would show the iads or Google ad-sense.

I don't get why it's so hard to just add a radio button when adding a new adv. that lets me choose 'html code' or 'upload your own banner image' this would solve the problem.

Also of course if iads is on it would rotate through banners i have added via adv. and iads.

If any one getting problem to understand so I am explaining it in bit detail:

As I am creating an a application for the customer and he want to operate the iAds , Google ad-sense (Ad-mob) or any other adverting SDK through the Admin panel of the application. He wants to put the Html code and want to get display over the application.

I have also shared him the below link of the authenticate website which are stated below.

https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/68724?hl=en

https://support.google.com/admob/answer/2952815?hl=en

https://developer.apple.com/support/appstore/iad-app-network/

Please help me out if there is any other way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible. we have limited access from admob and iads